# ed25519.Public result is different

Tags: go, cryptography, ed25519

Using the package https://github.com/golang/crypto/tree/master/ed25519 i m trying to get a public key for a given private key.

Those data are from http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0044.html: test 2 (mutable with salt)

Problem is, ed25519.Public() won t return the same public key when i fed it with the given private key.
The golang implementation returns the last 32 bytes of the PVK. But in my test data this is unexpected.

The code here https://play.golang.org/p/UJNPCyuGQB

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    priv := "e06d3183d14159228433ed599221b80bd0a5ce8352e4bdf0262f76786ef1c74db7e7a9fea2c0eb269d61e3b38e450a22e754941ac78479d6c54e1faf6037881d"
    pub := "77ff84905a91936367c01360803104f92432fcd904a43511876df5cdf3e7e548"
    sig := "6834284b6b24c3204eb2fea824d82f88883a3d95e8b4a21b8c0ded553d17d17ddf9a8a7104b1258f30bed3787e6cb896fca78c58f8e03b5f18f14951a87d9a08"
    // d := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(priv))
    privb, _ := hex.DecodeString(priv)
    pvk := ed25519.PrivateKey(privb)
    buffer := []byte("4:salt6:foobar3:seqi1e1:v12:Hello World!")
    sigb := ed25519.Sign(pvk, buffer)
    pubb, _ := hex.DecodeString(pub)
    sigb2, _ := hex.DecodeString(sig)
    log.Println(ed25519.Verify(pubb, buffer, sigb))
    log.Printf("%x\n", pvk.Public())
    log.Printf("%x\n", sigb)
    log.Printf("%x\n", sigb2)
}
```

How to generate the same public key than the bep using golang ?

Comment: to add more on that, i looked into https://github.com/orlp/ed25519 at https://github.com/orlp/ed25519/blob/master/src/keypair.c#L15 it generates (i think) the PBK, and its ge_p3_tobytes is way more complex https://github.com/orlp/ed25519/blob/master/src/ge.c#L321 the golang version is https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ed25519/ed25519.go#L43

Comment: Note, this also applies to Tor v3 onion service addresses

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to different ed25519 private key formats. An ed25519 key starts out as a 32 byte *seed*. This seed is hashed with SHA512 to produce 64 bytes (a couple of bits are flipped too). The first 32 bytes of these are used to generate the public key (which is also 32 bytes), and the last 32 bytes are used in the generation of the signature.

The Golang private key format is the 32 byte seed concatenated with the 32 byte public key. The private keys in the Bittorrent document you are using are the 64 byte result of the hash (or possibly just 64 random bytes that are used the same way as the hash result).

Since it’s not possible to reverse the hash, you can’t convert the Bittorrent keys to a format that the Golang API will accept.

You can produce a version of the Golang lib based on the existing package.

The following code depends on the internal package `golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519`, so if you want to use it you will need to copy that package out so that it is available to you code. It’s also very “rough and ready”, I’ve basically just copied the chunks of code needed from the existing code to get this to work.

Note that the public key and signature formats are the same, so as long as you are not sharing private keys you don’t need to use this code to get a working implementation. You will only need it if you want to check the test vectors.

First generating the public key from a private key:

```
// Generate the public key corresponding to the already hashed private
// key.
//
// This code is mostly copied from GenerateKey in the
// golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519 package, from after the SHA512
// calculation of the seed.
func getPublicKey(privateKey []byte) []byte {
    var A edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement
    var hBytes [32]byte
    copy(hBytes[:], privateKey)
    edwards25519.GeScalarMultBase(&A, &hBytes)
    var publicKeyBytes [32]byte
    A.ToBytes(&publicKeyBytes)

    return publicKeyBytes[:]
}
```

Next generating a signature:

```
// Calculate the signature from the (pre hashed) private key, public key
// and message.
//
// This code is mostly copied from the Sign function from
// golang.org/x/crypto/ed25519, from after the SHA512 calculation of the
// seed.
func sign(privateKey, publicKey, message []byte) []byte {

    var privateKeyA [32]byte
    copy(privateKeyA[:], privateKey) // we need this in an array later
    var messageDigest, hramDigest [64]byte

    h := sha512.New()
    h.Write(privateKey[32:])
    h.Write(message)
    h.Sum(messageDigest[:0])

    var messageDigestReduced [32]byte
    edwards25519.ScReduce(&messageDigestReduced, &messageDigest)
    var R edwards25519.ExtendedGroupElement
    edwards25519.GeScalarMultBase(&R, &messageDigestReduced)

    var encodedR [32]byte
    R.ToBytes(&encodedR)

    h.Reset()
    h.Write(encodedR[:])
    h.Write(publicKey)
    h.Write(message)
    h.Sum(hramDigest[:0])
    var hramDigestReduced [32]byte
    edwards25519.ScReduce(&hramDigestReduced, &hramDigest)

    var s [32]byte
    edwards25519.ScMulAdd(&s, &hramDigestReduced, &privateKeyA, &messageDigestReduced)

    signature := make([]byte, 64)
    copy(signature[:], encodedR[:])
    copy(signature[32:], s[:])

    return signature
}
```

Finally we can use these two functions to demonstrate the test vectors:

```
privateKeyHex := "e06d3183d14159228433ed599221b80bd0a5ce8352e4bdf0262f76786ef1c74db7e7a9fea2c0eb269d61e3b38e450a22e754941ac78479d6c54e1faf6037881d"

expectedPublicKey := "77ff84905a91936367c01360803104f92432fcd904a43511876df5cdf3e7e548"
expectedSig := "6834284b6b24c3204eb2fea824d82f88883a3d95e8b4a21b8c0ded553d17d17ddf9a8a7104b1258f30bed3787e6cb896fca78c58f8e03b5f18f14951a87d9a08"

privateKey, _ := hex.DecodeString(privateKeyHex)
publicKey := getPublicKey(privateKey)

fmt.Printf("Calculated key: %x\n", publicKey)
fmt.Printf("Expected key:   %s\n", expectedPublicKey)
keyMatches := expectedPublicKey == hex.EncodeToString(publicKey)
fmt.Printf("Public key matches expected: %v\n", keyMatches)

buffer := []byte("4:salt6:foobar3:seqi1e1:v12:Hello World!")
calculatedSig := sign(privateKey, publicKey, buffer)

fmt.Printf("Calculated sig: %x\n", calculatedSig)
fmt.Printf("Expected sig:   %s\n", expectedSig)
sigMatches := expectedSig == hex.EncodeToString(calculatedSig)
fmt.Printf("Signature matches expected: %v\n", sigMatches)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I ll arrange with the copy-paste code, your solution is clear and straight, this is really appreciated. I did not understand why (golang|bitorrent) provides a different format, maybe someone knows about that ?

Comment: For anyone looking, I put this as a library at https://github.com/cretz/bine/tree/master/torutil/ed25519