# How to generate bytes array from PublicKey

Tags: go, cryptography, ecdsa

I'm use [crypto lib](https://golang.org/src/crypto/), ran into a problem: I need to convert the `PublicKey` type into `byte[]`, as it can be done with a private key:

```
privkey.D.Bytes()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you see the documentation? `type PublicKey interface{}` It can be anything, and is probably not directly convertible to a byte slice. For instance an RSA PublicKey is a struct that contains a modulus and exponent. Converting this to a `[]byte` is meaningless and impossible anyway. This question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). You should instead describe what you are really trying to accomplish by doing this. Then we can find a solution for the true underlying problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I use another package in which I need to pass an array of bytes to the method. However, since I only have an interface, it's impossible to do it

Comment: What other package? What method?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i use [this](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/issues/974#issuecomment-320462200) way, i need to get public key in byte[] format for use `btcutil.NewAddressPubKey(wif.SerializePubKey(),
  &chaincfg.MainNetParams)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ecdsa.PrivateKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PrivateKey) is a struct:

```
type PrivateKey struct {
        PublicKey
        D *big.Int
}
```

So `privkey.D.Bytes()` returns you the bytes of the `D` big integer.

Similarly, [`ecdsa.PublicKey`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey):

```
type PublicKey struct {
        elliptic.Curve
        X, Y *big.Int
}
```

You may do the same with `pubkey.X` and `pubkey.Y` fields. These will give you 2 separate byte slices. If you need to merge them into one, you need to come up with some kind of "format", e.g. encoding the length of the first slice (the result of `pubkey.X.Bytes()`) using 4 bytes, then the first slice, then the length (4 bytes again) of the 2nd slice, and the second slice itself.

Best would be to use the [`elliptic.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#Marshal) function for this:

> ```
> func Marshal(curve Curve, x, y *big.Int) []byte
> ```
>
> Marshal converts a point into the uncompressed form specified in section 4.3.6 of ANSI X9.62.

Example using it:

```
var pubkey *ecdsa.PublicKey = // ...

data := elliptic.Marshal(pubkey, pubkey.X, pubkey.Y)
```

Comment: @Folleah, While it's tangential, it might worth mentioning that at least 3 "wire formats" were created to store/transmit cryptographic material—pkcs#7, PFX and pkcs#12 (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)). The latter is arguably the most common these days, and [`github.com/SSLMate/go-pkcs12`](https://github.com/SSLMate/go-pkcs12) allows to create PKCS#12-formatted containers. [See also](https://godoc.org/?q=pkcs).

Comment: Instead of inventing your own encoding it would be wise to use the [Marshal](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/elliptic/#Marshal) function to get a standardized uncompressed point to represent the public key. Using a container format such as suggested by the comment above is of course also a good option, but it is not similar to storing D.

Comment: note for if you are using rsa: `privkey.PublicKey.N.Bytes()`

Answer (score 4):

For the lovely folks looking for a solution when it comes to `ed25519/crypto`. I banged my head for nearly 3 hours until I figured it out:

```golang
func getPrivateKey() ed25519.PrivateKey {
    // TODO You fill in this one
}

func main() {
    prvKey := getPrivateKey() // Get the private key

    pubKey := prvKey.Public().(ed25519.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Errorf("Could not assert the public key to ed25519 public key")
    }
    pubKeyBytes := []byte(pubKey)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct - the format of ed25519 private keys seems to be that of the seed concatenated with the public key. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44874097/1623885