# Generate an Ed25519 public key in OpenSSL - without hashing and clamping

Tags: openssl, clamp, ed25519

According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44874097/569825), this is a question of *"key formats"*. OpenSSL uses the **key as seed** and hashes and clamps it in preparation for generating the public key:

> An ed25519 key starts out as a 32 byte *seed*. This seed is hashed with SHA512 to produce 64 bytes (a couple of bits are flipped too). The first 32 bytes of these are used to generate the public key (which is also 32 bytes), and the last 32 bytes are used in the generation of the signature.

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 | openssl pkey -text
```

**Can I have OpenSSL omit these steps so that it generates the public key directly from the key as integer?**

... or can I work around this using a different command?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? Clamping has security reasons. And the signature algorithm requires another 32 bytes sequence, for which the second 32 bytes of the SHA512 hash is used. How do you want to handle this? That would probably amount to a (rather insecure) custom implementation.